# SSRS: How to make a group instance sort to the top based on value in a particular row/column?

Tags: sorting, reporting-services

I have this in my SSRS report:

```
Group(instance 1)

   Row 1: 1--2--3 <<sort by this number at this location (3)

   Row 2: 4--5--6

   Row 3: 7--8--9

Group(instance 2)

   Row 1: 10-11-12 << 

   Row 2: 13-14-15

   Row 3: 16-17-18
```

I want to sort that group using the field Row 1/Column 3. I tried using First(Field) as my sort expression, but it gives an error saying I cannot use Last/First to sort inside groups.

What I want for my end result is the following:

```
Group(instance 2)

   Row 1: 10-11-12

   Row 2: 13-14-15

   Row 3: 16-17-18

Group(instance 1)

   Row 1: 1--2--3

   Row 2: 4--5--6

   Row 3: 7--8--9
```

Because 12 is larger than 3 I'd like instance 2 to sort to the top.

Answer (score 0):

Try sort by expression: =CDec(Fields!XXXX)